# Visual Studio2012 - a class not accessible in unit test

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

Lame question, but quite irritating.
I am doing a small WPF application.

Added a unit test project to the solution and a reference to my main project.
When I am accessing the main project namespace from the unit test, I cannot see custom classes created by me.

Any hints?

Comment: Are the classes public?

Comment: can I delete my post :D?
Assumed public by default and did not even consider this :D :D.
THX PCG! solved!

Comment: You can delete it since there is no answer yet.

Comment: @EmilNa just click `delete` link under question tags